# No data is deployed on the contract address!

Tags: testnets

I add a new Smart Contract and create it, but I get the following bug. Why is the contract not created? I take the etherium wallet and the ropsten testnetwork
The first picture include the constructor. Thanks for helping.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your are sending 0.2 ether with the contract creation but your constructor is not payable.

Either do not send ether when creating the contract or modify constructor to be payable.

```
contract A {
    address internal owner;
    constructor() public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```